# How to establish communication channel between javascript and cgi in C?

Tags: javascript, c, cgi

How to make javascript communicate with cgi script in C? For example trying
to send incremented int value from CGI to javascript and display it in browser.
On client side is hidden iframe with get method for cgi script :

```
 <<html><head><title>Javascript cgi</title>  
<style type="text/css">
  #hiddenframe { display:none; } 
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var value = 0;
function init() {
  document.getElementById('thevalue').innerHTML = value; 
  setInterval("get_value()", 1000);
}

function get_value() {
  value = thescript.value;
  document.getElementById('thevalue').innerHTML = value; 
  thescript.location.href = 'http://localhost/homecgi/cgi.exe';  
}    
onload = init;    
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="hiddenframe">
 <iframe src="http://localhost/homecgi/cgi.exe" name="thescript"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="thevalue"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On server side cgi in C:

```
int main() 
{ 
int j=100;     
char *data_get;
char *method;

  printf("%s%c%c\n", "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);            
  printf(" <html><title>hello</title><body> \n");       

     method = getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"); 
     data_get = getenv("QUERY_STRING"); 

     if( !strcmp(method, "GET") ){
       printf("<br>Method %s\n", method);
       printf("<br> data_get %s\n", data_get);

       printf("<script>");
       printf(" var value = %d ", j++);
       printf("</script>");   
    }
    else if(!strcmp(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"), "POST")){

     }         
  printf("<p><a href=http://localhost/homecgi/index.html >Back</a> </p>");
  printf(" </body></html>");      
  return 0; 
}
```

This way only j=100 is printing. How can every incremented value
j in cgi send to javascript and print it on screen? How to establish
communication channel between javascript and cgi in C?

Comment: Are you trying to update the value based on a user-action, or is the event initiated by the server? [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) might be able to solve your problem, otherwise check something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Comment: It is initiated by reading and changing some values on server and representing them on browser. Its embedded http server with only cgi on server side, it seems cant use XMLHttpRequest. But not sure for socket.io, got to check if can use it and how.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to achieve? If all you want to do is fetch some value from the server at regular intervals, you should do it the AJAX way with XMLHttpRequest and simply send the value across the wire. I haven’t used C for ages, but on every invocation your `main()` assigns `100` to `j`, prints `j` while doing a post-increment and then returns, obviously it is always going to write `100`. If you want separate invocations of your script to share information, you need to persist that information somewhere outside the script^^

Comment: But how to use ajax with cgi in c? How to response to ajax request from cgi script in C? Any tutorial...?

Comment: Anyone!? Tutorial on using ajax and cgi scripting in C? Is there javascript objects to communicate with cgi server in C?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some thing with ajax and php. This is client side with XHR:

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script>
       var response;
     </script>
    </head>

    <body>   
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input type="button" onclick="sendRequest()" value="String"> <br>

     <script>      
      function sendRequest() {        
        var http = createRequestObject(); 
        http.open("GET", "phptoajax.php?p=");
        http.onreadystatechange = function () { handleResponse(http); };
        http.send(null);        
    }

     function createRequestObject() {
        var http;
        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        else {
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return http;
    }

    function handleResponse(http) {    
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            response = http.responseText;        
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response + "<br>";        
        }
    }     
     </script>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Sending something to php. Php then returns string Hello World:

```
<?php    
  $j = $_GET["p"];
  $j = $j . " Hello World";
  echo   $j ;    
?>
```

Only with echo string value $j, http.responseText get this
value back and client prints "Hello World" to browser. It works.

But when try this in cgi i get stuck. On client side have to change to
cgi script:

```
http.open("GET", "cgi.exe?p=");
```

CGI C:

```
int main() 
{ 

char *data_get;
char *string = "Hello World";

  printf("%s%c%c\n", "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);     
  printf(" <html><title>hello</title><body> \n");       

     data_get = getenv("QUERY_STRING"); 

     if( !strcmp(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"), "GET") ){

         // printf("<br> data_get: %s <br>\n", data_get);             
         printf("%s\n", string); // Sending to browser    
     }
    else if(!strcmp(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD"), "POST")){
        printf("<br> POST METHOD");           
     }          
   printf(" </body></html>");      
  return 0; 
}
```

Cgi did not send anything to browser. How to with printf("%s\n", string); print "Hello World" to browser like did it with  echo $j; from php ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**

Problem was path to cgi script in line : http.open("GET", "cgi.exe?p=");.

Have to put full path on local host:

```
http.open("GET", "http://localhost/cgi-bin/cgi.exe?p=");
```